# Change css and html of address within book.phtml

Tags: magento-1.8, frontend, address, customer-account

I want to change how the address within book.phtml is displayed on frontend. In detail it is this part of code:

`<h4><?php echo $this->__('Default Billing Address') ?></h4>
 <address>
   <?php echo $this->getPrimaryBillingAddressHtml() ?>

 </address>`

source code shows this:

`<address>
   John Doe<br/>
   Company<br />
   Street Address<br />
   State, Province Zip Code<br/>
   Country<br/>
   T: 59874953847983<br />
</address>`

I would like to have something like this:

`<address>
  <div class="tagContainer">
   <span class="oddTag">John Doe<br/></span>
   <span class="evenTag">Company<br /></span>
   <span class="oddTag">Street Address<br /></span>
   <span class="evenTag">State, Province Zip Code<br/></span>
   <span class="oddTag">Country<br/></span>
   <span class="evenTag">T: 59874953847983<br /></span>
  </div>
</address>`

In which file can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in your .phtml file

1) get address ID of logged in Customer

```
$_pAddsses = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling());
```

2) load address by address ID

```
$BillingAddress = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getAddressById($_pAddsses);
```

3) Now get details

```
<address>
  <div class="tagContainer">
   <span class="oddTag"><?php echo $BillingAddress->getFirstname() ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $BillingAddress->getLastname();?><br/></span>
   <span class="evenTag"><?php echo $BillingAddress->getCompany() ?><br /></span>
   <span class="oddTag"><?php echo $BillingAddress->getStreet();?><br /></span>
   <span class="evenTag"><?php echo $BillingAddress->getPostcode() ?><br/></span>
   <span class="oddTag"><?php echo $BillingAddress->getCountry() ?><br/></span>
   <span class="evenTag"><?php echo $BillingAddress->getTelephone(); ?><br /></span>
  </div>
</address>
```

Comment: awesome thank you for the fast help. Would you be so kind and let me also know where I would find those functions getFirstname(), getCompany() etc.?

Comment: You can check all functions definitions and reference here http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?_functions/index.html